# unable to scroll to the bottom of the div in web page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html page that includes bunch of divs. I call it left div where I populate this div with jstree nodes. I have set the style of this div to be this in css:

```
#left {
                padding:0 0 0 0;
                border: 0 0 0 0;
                height: 1000px;
                width: 350px;
                overflow: scroll;
                float: left;
                margin-top:80px;
                position: fixed;

                   }
```

However, when I load the jstree nodes into this, when I scroll down, I cannot see the bottom of the div where some nodes are. Is there method in jquery or css to make sure I can see all the content in the div when scroll down?

Comment: margin-top:0px;    margin-top:80px;

Comment: some other style is making the problem.. screenshot or more code will be better

Comment: that was a typo, correcting that did not fix it.

Comment: dude then correct it in question

Comment: to me it looks like the height of your div is bigger than your browser window height. When your div is fixed it don't scrolls, so you can't reach what is out of the viewport. Put no height and margin-top in. Instead use top:80px; bottom:0px;

Comment: @Sven Bieder, that kinda worked but my left div now does not cover the the whole page, it does not really look good. It ends somewhere in the middle of the browser window. Any ideas how I can strech the height of the div to the full browser size?

Comment: For that I must see the complete or even better make a jsfiddle, that I can make myself a picture how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

If all of the other div's are inside your div with id left, then you can give `overflow:hidden;` property and remove the height property. It will display everything that is there, inside left div, provided the inner div's have valid content.

Comment: if there are too much of content in that div what will happen if he apply overflow:hidden;

Comment: @zod, overflow:hidden will help him to clear floats for the divs that lie inside the left div. off course if the content doesnt fall within limits it will be hidden as the property says

Comment: left div is by itself on the left side of the page, need to have overflow: auto; to make sure I can scroll if there are lots of jstree nodes. I can scroll but Icannot go down the end of the div.

Comment: @MikeDude thats probably you have position fixed there

Comment: @refhat, I must have a position: fixed so that my top div which includes the header dont move when I scroll the page.

Comment: @MikeDude how about creating header in a seperate div and positioning that as fixed

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
        height: 1000px;
```

to

```
        min-height: 1000px;
```

this will expand the height if the contents exceed 1000px

Comment: when I do that, I loose scroll bar on the right of the div. I need to have the scroll bar on the right of the div.

Comment: oh , ok , do min-height in the div with the scroll bar then

Comment: what do you mean, I just tried that that takes away the scrolling functionality.

Comment: can you post an example , or a link to the problem